# Expert proficiency with Advanced weapons

Tags: weapons, pathfinder-2e, proficiency

I can become *trained* with any Advanced weapon through the [Weapon Proficiency](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=866) feat, if I take it enough times. How can I become an *expert* with it?

Taking the various Weapon Familiarity feats (like [Elven Weapon Familiarity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=14)) make Advanced weapons related to an ancestry Martial, but what about a [Daikyu](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=125) for example? How can a Ranger become *expert* with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Be a Fighter

[Fighters](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=7) naturally are trained in all advanced weapons and become expert in one [weapon group](https://2e.aonprd.com/WeaponGroups.aspx) (axes/swords/etc.) at level 5 with Fighter Weapon Mastery, master in one weapon group at level 13 with Weapon Legend and expert in all others, then master in all advanced weapons at level 19 with Versatile Legend.

### Be a Provocator

This unusual archetype from the *Agents of Edgewatch* adventure path has a 16th-level feat [Performance Weapon Expert](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2216) which grants expert proficiency in the advanced weapon chosen as part of taking the 10th-level [dedication feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2211).

### Treat them as Martial Weapons

Several advanced weapons have an ancestry trait associated with them, allowing them to be wielded as martial weapons by characters with the appropriate weapon familiarity ancestry feat like [Dwarven Weapon Familiarity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2). Humans have a variant of this in [Unconventional Weaponry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=72) allowing them to do so with any uncommon advanced weapon common in another culture, even those without an ancestry trait.

Fighters have a 6th-level feat [Advanced Weapon Training](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=378), allowing you to treat any weapon group of advanced weapons as martial weapons. Any character can pick this up with a Fighter Archetype requiring 14 Str, 14 Dex, and 3 class feats for the [Fighter Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=709), [Basic Maneuver](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=710), then [Advanced Maneuver](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=713) as a 12th-level feat or higher.

Beyond those options there are also two archetypes which grant specific weapons or groups a similar benefit:

- [Aldori Swordlord](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=876): Gain proficiency in [aldori dueling swords](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=256) matching your highest weapon proficiency
- [Archer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=47): [Advanced Bow Training](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1887) grants the benefit of Advanced Weapon Training for fighters as a  6th-level feat for any character, for advanced bows specifically

Comment: So unless you are a Fighter, or start playing above level 11, just forget about advanced weapons without an ancestry trait

Comment: Well, or you could just have them as trained. Probably not worth it after level 5 when most martial classes get expert in Martial weapons but advanced weapons are better than martial ones. Up to you if it's worth the reduced to-hit.

Comment: Advanced weapons are usaully a _tiny_ bit better than similar martials, definitely not worth -2 to attack

Comment: Specifically for Bows, there's an archer dedication feat at level 6 to treat them as advanced.  Unfortunately the archer dedication itself is a dead feat for a ranger.  https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1887

Comment: @András FWIW, [Unconventional Weaponry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=72) also allows for weapons "common in another culture". Definitely up to your GM there, and probably not something to rely on for PFS, but you might be able to get a boon for it in PFS. I don't see anything wrong (as a GM) with allowing any uncommon weapon for Unconventional Weaponry, especially for the fairly meh Daikyu.